# Does Hazelcast client gets data from client near cache if using Entry Processor for data access?

Tags: hazelcast

We want to configure near cache on client so that we can handle high TPS items and avoid network call to server. But most of our data access operation are using Entry Processor because our object size is big & we want to return small subset of data from server.

But according to documentation, Near Cache works only when you access data via map.get(k) or cache.get(k) methods.

Is it possible to near cache selected keys? I know its not possible but just want to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible, you can, however, have a look at the Continuous Query Caching feature (something like a clientside materialized view), which might help depending on the EntryProcessor operation you do. http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.4/manual/html-single/index.html#continuous-query-cache

Comment: I think we can use continuous query cache. Can we disable updates to continuous query cache if distributed IMap receives an update? Can we configure TTL on continuous query cache?

Comment: You could probably use a always-false predicate but I'm not really sure this'll work. Not sure this is actually possible tbh.